# Overriding explicit rules in Makefiles

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile system that dynamically generates rules to build lists of files for different platforms. For various reasons implicit rules cannot be used as there is no common pattern to apply, but rather the output of various functions over file lists.

Now I'm trying to add automatic dependency generation in a way that it's triggered only for the targets that are needed to be built. The normal way to do this is to define implicit rules that generate dependencies and then include or define explicit rules requiring these dependencies as prerequisites for the same target (see http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html for an example). This works because make automatically overrides implicit rules with explicit versions of the same rule without complaining.

However, since I have no option to use implicit rules I'm trying to figure out a way to do this. I see only two approaches:

1. Dynamically rewrite explicit rules and get a "warning: overriding commands for target" for each one.
2. Find a way tell Make to drop an existing rule definition, so I can provide a new one.

Since AFAIK there is no way to do the 2nd option, does anybody know how I can suppress the "overriding commands for target" warnings? Any other suggestions for overriding explicit rules and evaluating them again with new prerequisites?

Comment: A makefile can work as intended with only explicit rules and no implicit rules. Can you provide a simple example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: For example, this but without pattern rules: http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html#norule  Not necessarily using makedepend, but any way to produce new rules with the right dependencies for the same targets. In this example this is done via the include below.

Comment: While your build system may very well require the complexity of an auto-dependency mechanism like that described via the link you provided, you may not -- I have personally seen a lot of very bad solutions to the perceived deficiencies of `make` and the problem of cross-platform -- i.e. "portable" -- builds in the last 35 years or so (Imake, anyone?). Can you provide a sample explicit target-dependency-rules fragment or two to demonstrate what you need to do? Also, are all builds performed on Unix/Linux/Mac OS X or are there other build platforms with `make`, but without a full Unix tool set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no way to replace explicit rules without getting that message (well of course since GNU make is open source, you could modify the code and build your own version).

The longer answer is that I think your initial assumption is incorrect.  I don't understand what you mean by *this works because make automatically overrides implicit rules with explicit versions of the same rule without complaining*.

What you appear to be thinking of is prerequisite statements that do not have recipes, like:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) ...

foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h
foo.o: biz.h baz.h
```

etc.  The rule in GNU make is that there can be only one rule *defining a recipe* for any given target (single-colon targets anyway).  There can be as many rules defining only prerequisite relationships, without defining recipes, as you like.  When these prerequisite-only rules are seen they simply *append* the additional prerequisites to the list of current prerequisites.

And, there is no difference between implicit or explicit rules here; for example the above example could be written:

```
foo.o : foo.c
        $(CC) ...

foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h
foo.o: biz.h baz.h
```

and that's perfectly legal and will not give you any warnings.

It seems that there is a problem in your makefile and you've done a bit of leaping to conclusions about what the problem is, then instead of describing the problem itself you're asking how to work around the conclusion.  If you back up and show us an example of the makefile where you're seeing the warning generated (and show how you invoke make and past the warning you get), we can probably better assist you.